# Python Soup Scarpe Hidden Element

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scarpe a smart link from amazon, in order to get that link, i need to click on button 'text'.

```
html before clicking : <textarea readonly="" id="amzn-ss-text-shortlink-textarea" class="amzn-ss-text-shortlink-textarea"></textarea>

html after clicking :  <textarea readonly="" id="amzn-ss-text-shortlink-textarea" class="amzn-ss-text-shortlink-textarea">https://amzn.to/3fiCAjW</textarea>
```

the xpath doesn't change before/after clicking text button : `//textarea[@class='amzn-ss-text-shortlink-textarea']`

is it possible to scarpe that element with beautifulsoup ?

my code :

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Faffiliate-program.amazon.com%2F&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_associates_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&marketPlaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&language=en_US&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="email"]').send_keys('myemail')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="password"]').send_keys('mypassword')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signInSubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(35)


HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
# url's to scrape
prod_tracker_URLS = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0036OS6KI'

# fetch the url
page = requests.get(prod_tracker_URLS, headers=HEADERS)

# create the object that will contain all the info in the url
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# product smart link
smartlink = tree.xpath("//textarea[@class='amzn-ss-text-shortlink-textarea']/text()")
print(smartlink)
```

output : `[]`

[image: element image]

**Before clicking**
[image]

Comment: I'm no Amazon affiliate so I don't have all these options to analyse your problem. However, you could try to analyse the networking tab and see whether any additional data is loaded when you click the _Text_ button. It nothing shows up you could try o search all the files in the network tab (use Chrome, not Firefox) for the ID (2D5T..) and see where it comes from. There is probably some JavaScript file or even a JSON that adds the `div` along with the key to the DOM.

Comment: that link who contains 2D5T changes each time  @Gregor